# NSAttributedString relative font-size custom attribute

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, textkit

In CSS, you have the [font-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp) property that can be used to specify font sizes relative to the rest of the text.

What would it take to implement a custom **relative font-size** attribute in iOS (requiring only iOS 7 compatibility)? Are there any third-party solutions that already implement this?

(I would expect the solution to be useful for everything that supports attributed text: UILabel, UITextView, ... the titleLabel in a UIButton, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to define attributes for your own custom headers that are relative to the user's preferred body font size (i.e, Dynamic Type).

```
UIFontDescriptor *bodyFontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];

NSNumber *bodyFontSize = bodyFont.fontAttributes[UIFontDescriptorSizeAttribute];

float bodyFontSizeValue = [bodyFontSize floatValue];

UIFont *headerOneFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:bodyFontDescriptor size:bodyFontSizeValue * 3.0f];

NSDictionary *headerOneAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : headerOneFont};

UIFont *headerTwoFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:bodyFontDescriptor size:bodyFontSizeValue * 2.0f];

NSDictionary *headerTwoAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : headerTwoFont};
```

This code is based on code from Chapters 4 and 5 of "iOS 7 by Tutorials", by raywenderlich.com.

The attribute dictionaries can be used to initialize attributed string objects, which in turn, can be displayed in UILabels, UITextViews, and UITextFields.